# Angular 12 : Async Call on Navigation

Tags: html, angular, typescript, async-await

On one of the Component I have `Download` feature.

It has 100K records where API give response & user able to Download it. It will take 5-10 minutes to process. We don't want to block the user by navigating to other pages.

So is it possible to achieve it? Like user able to navigate to other components.

We can show message like your Download is in progress. Once it ready we will update you. And user able to download it.

Comment: You didn't mention what you are using for the API or if you have control over its behavior. My approach to this would be to create an API endpoint that initiates a background task to generate the file. This endpoint would immediately return a token of some sort that is used to identify the background process. Then provide another API endpoint to determine the status (either by polling or web socket). Then a third API endpoint to download the file when it is ready.